# setting CHMOD permissions for each user for their own folder

Tags: linux, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
MasterDir="/home/darkeve/Documents/OS/master/"         
USERHOME="/home/darkeve/Documents/OS/UNIX"   
MasterFile="filenames.txt"

while read -r line; do
mkdir "UNIX/$line"
for FILENAME in `cat $MasterFile`
do
    cp "$MasterDir/$FILENAME" $USERHOME/$line
done
done < usernames.lnk

chown $USER:$USER $USERHOME/$USER -R
CHMDO 700 $USERHOME/$USER -R
```

I am trying to set CHMOD 700 permission so each user has access to their own folder only within the UNIX folder. The users come from a list of names that are written in the usernames.lnk folder which was copied and then each folder was created with their own name in the UNIX folder. So I am trying to set up the CHMOD permission so they can only have access to their own folder and nothing else.

So far the only error I am getting is

chown: cannot access `/home/darkeve/Documents/OS/UNIX/darkeve` : No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/home/darkeve/Documents/OS/UNIX/darkeve` : No such file or directory

So does this mean it set the permissions correctly but there is an error in the code to make the script thing there is a folder called "darkeve" in the unix folder?

Comment: ... You are running this as root and there is a `/home/darkeve/Documents/OS/UNIX/darkeve` on your FS (as in "you've checked this with `ls /home/darkeve/Documents/OS/UNIX/darkeve`, right...?

Comment: the problem is there isn't supposed to be a user called "darkeve" in the first place so I don't understand how its trying to change CHMOD permissions for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: and I am running the script whilst im in /home/darkeve/Documents/OS/ on the terminal and i enter /home/darkeve/Documents/OS/taskscript.sh

Comment: You should firstly do the `chmod` and then `chown`. Otherwise, you will not be able to access to those files.